# Core data - Distinct values

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm having trouble with core data and fetching distinct values. What I want to do is fetch records that are distinct by one property, but I want to fetch more than one property of a record. If I set `setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"firstAtrb", @"secondAtrb"]` (more than one) then `setReturnsDistinctValues:YES` returns distinct values by properties defined in setPropertiesToFetch. Is it possible to define a property by which fetch should be distinct but at the same time define more than one property to fetch?

Comment: Sorry not 100% sure what it is you want to do here? Are you wanting to get all of your data form the database where a certain property is set to a certain value..?

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution that i used on you can filter the results by distinct heres and example [myResults valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfSets.foo"] and a the refrence link [retrieving distinct values core data](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/230192-retrieving-the-distinct-values-of-an-attribute-for-core-data-entity.html)

Comment: While interesting, I don't think this answers the question. I think George's comment is warranted, and perhaps paxx is not being clear about the intended goal. You either fetch distinct values by all of the properties requested or not. Requiring additional properties either means including them in the distinct fetch or fetching all entities.

Comment: yeah.. @fichek is right.. I want to fetch multiple properties but i want the result to be distinct only by one of them.. it's a classic sql query.. SELECT DISTINCT(someAttribute), someOtherAttribute FROM someTable WHERE ...